MERGE request how to set in Postman
I have oData batch extracted from chrome:
MERGE FooEntitySet(Param1='x',Param2='y')
And it contain date i want to merge/update:
{"__metadata":
{"uri":"ServerURL/Service/FooEntitySet(Param1='x',Param2='y')",
"type":"Service.FooEntityType"},
"Date":"\/Date(1716940800000)\/"
}

How to replicate it in postman? Server respond me with "Invalid entity metadata type 'Service.FooEntityType'" error most of the time.
I tried PATCH and also POST/PUT with header parameter x-http-method MERGE but it doesn't trigger backend method - it's rejected with http status 400 - bad request.
